# replacing #define with typedefs for bracket scope

Tags: string

I have a project in which basically i have to concatenate existing code.
Each code comes with its own #defines.
But defines are not touched by the compiler, but the preprocessor.

Each snippet of the program will exist in its own fucntion.

Is it possible to include the #defines of each program - now each function, inside this function (and visible only to this function's scope)?

The proper way to do it, would be to replace text reassignment from #define to typedef?

I understand typedef is originally for defining types. But can it be used here? Is there another alternative?

Comment: What are these macros used for? You can replace them with different things depending on what they are, but you may lose execution efficiency.

Comment: The macros are used for text replacement. For example #define value 255

Comment: Then you would use `const` variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#define value 255
```

Can be replaced with

```
const int value = 255;
```

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to use "namespace { ... }" to create local defines for a *.cpp file.
In the Arduino IDE all *.ino files are combined in a single *.cpp file, therefor the "namespace" is not very useful.

When you create new tabs in the Arduino IDE and name them *.cpp, then you have different *.cpp files. Then you can use the "namespace" to create defines that are only valid for that *.cpp file.

More info: [Hackaday: Using Modern C++ Techniques with Arduino](http://hackaday.com/2017/05/05/using-modern-c-techniques-with-arduino/)